# Is there a way to create non-filled TextInputEditText with TextInputLayout in 1.1.0+?

Tags: android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext, material-components-android

I'm trying to migrate from Material components 1.0.0 to 1.1.0-alpha07 in order to be able to use ExposedDropdown style.
However, it messes up all my `TextInputEditText`s as they are meant to be neither outlined nor filled.

I've tried setting `TextInputEditText` box backgrounds to transparent color, but that ends up making their fill completely white instead of making them see-through and exposing what's behind them (which is a brand color with gradient that spans more than the edit field, and that is why I can't just set its color to the background color as it just won't fit the gradient).

**So, the question:** Is there any way to keep the old-fashioned non-filled EditTexts in 1.1.0+ (while still using them inside `TextInputLayout`)?

Note: 
I have to say that excluding a simple option to have edit fields non-filled (as they used to be) is a huge mistake since it almost completely shuts down painless migration to 1.1.0, you now basically have to force your design to change first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a rather simple answer to the problem.

The solution is to use `app:boxBackgroundMode="none"` with the filled box style.

You can also put an application-wide style for text input layouts (also applying the aforementioned attribute) using `textInputStyle` attribute in your app's theme and supplying the desired style.

As a side note, this just points out the catastrophic lack of easily-accessible documentation and guides that plagues this library.

Comment: the line below goes away too with solution tho'

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `TextInputEditText` background to transparent worked for me. 
My theme's parent is `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar`.

Another possibility is to use a `ThemeOverlay` for your `editTextStyle`:

```
<style name="Widget.YourTheme.TextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox>
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.YourTheme.TextInputEditText</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.YourTheme.TextInputEditText parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox">
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/Widget.YourTheme.TextInputEditText item>
</style>


<style name="Widget.YourTheme.TextInputEditText parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>


<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
   style="@style/Widget.YourTheme.TextInputLayout"
   ...
   <TextInputEditText>
      ...
   </TextInputEditText>
 </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: I haven't tried your solution, but I've found a much simpler one.

Comment: Setting `boxBackgroundMode="none"` works, but it removes the `EditText's` bottom line as well, which is not what I needed for my usecase.